# Refactoring webproject: php mysql javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Since my project gets bigger and bigger I start to loose overview :)
I have alot of Ajax requets and for ever request an appropriate file
like: "newbill.php","newcustomer.php" and so on..meaning for every singele request a new one?

My Question is: is there any way to somehow get around this?
What I thought of is to pass the name of a function within the POST of the ajax 
to call the appropriate function within the php..
but I somehow dont feel comfortable with it neither??

Sample(javascript)

```
    // Kundendaten updaten
$("a#updateKunde").click(function(evt){

    formSerial2 = $('#baseForm').serialize();
    evt.preventDefault();
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            **url: "ajax/updatecustomer.php"**,
            data: formSerial2,
            success: function(msg){                 
                $(".alert").html(msg)
                           .css("color","#66b451")
                           .hide()
                           .show('slow')
                           .fadeOut(2000)
                           .hide('slow');

            }
        });         
});
```

PHP-file(updatecostumer.php)

```
<?php 

    include_once("../_class/queries.php");

        $kn = $_POST['selKunden'];

        $vn = $_POST['ivname'];
        $na = $_POST['iname'];
        $st = $_POST['istrasse'];
        $pl = $_POST['iplz'];
        $or = $_POST['iort']; 
        $em = $_POST['iemail'];

        connect::getQuery("UPDATE  Kunde SET  vname =  '".$vn."', 
                             name =  '".$na."',
                             adresse =  '".$st."',
                             plz =  '".$pl."',
                             ort =  '".$or."',
                             email =  '".$em."' 
                             WHERE  Kunde.ID =".$kn."");                        


        echo(" Kunde Nr: ".$kn." wurde upgedated");

 ?>
```

Comment: You **MUST** sanitize all inputs before you use them in a query. You're wide open to SQL injections!

Comment: 9 questions asked, 7 with answers, none accepted.. not good odds of getting answers on this one.

Comment: suggest you move this questions to programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Polynominal  I'm aware of the the sanitize thing - thnks :)

Comment: @Jan-Henk  I considered a framework but I dont know if its realy necessary?

Comment: @Don Using a framework means you don't have to setup all the boilerplate code for handling requests yourself. You only have to write the code that actually does the work you need. But whether or not it is really necessary depends on the size of your codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so a few comments here..

First never ever ever take direct input and push to your DB.  Always escape entry from your users to avoid SQL Injection:

```
$st = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['istrasse']);
```

Secondly; you could have an action clause in your post to a file such as ajax.php. Through this you would then be able to handle different actions.  I wouldn't suggest passing a function name, but create a list of actions which lead you to the class you need done.  If you have common post parameters for various actions you could then take and reuse code on your ajax page rather than having multiple other pages out there doing the exact same escaping / querying.

Comment: What you mean by "action clause"? Do you mean I send an like: ?action=functionname" to the ajax.php? and within the ajax.php do a "swicth <functionnname> {..mysql stuff..}"?